# What is the use of crystallized Photosystems from cyanobacteria?

Tags: photosynthesis

I read a lot of articles about techniques for the crystallization of Photosystem I and II from cyanobacteria. My question is what is the reason for that and what can you do with Photosystem crystals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of crystallizing a molecule or molecular complex like a  Photosystem is usually to provide a crystal for [X-ray crystallography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography).  A crystal has its molecular components arranged in a structured systematic repeating pattern, and this repeated pattern allows the X-rays to reveal the 3-dimensional shape of one of the components.  Knowing the shape is of biological interest as it suggests how the molecules perform their function.